# close tcp connection but keep port open for new connections in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

Hi I have the following code that I got from geek of geeks this is the server side of the code:

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd, len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
   
    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   
    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
   
    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");
   
    // Now server is ready to listen and verification
    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    len = sizeof(cli);
   
    // Accept the data packet from client and verification
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);
    if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server accept the client...\n");
   
    // Function for chatting between client and server
    func(connfd);
   
    // After chatting close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}
```

The client has the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
 
    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
 
    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
 
    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))
        != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");
 
    // function for chat
    func(sockfd);
 
    // close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}
```

I would like to close the connection though the server side of the code and when the client is aware of that they create a new connection. The objective is for the server to be able to handle multiple clients.

In order to close the connection through the server I thought I had to close the `connfd` socket in order to allow new connections.

If I would like the client to restart a new connection how should the client proceed? IE should they make a new socket (`sockfd`) and restart everything from the beginning everytime they create a new connection? How can the TCP wait for a new connection after closing the socket (note that I would like to multithreaded this process afterward so I would have the server waiting for new connections) ?

Comment: You need to keep calling the accept method in order to accept new connections. If u want to use multithreading u can pass a new connfd to be handled in a new thread while the main "starting" thread goes back to accepting new connections

Comment: @mont_  So I have to close the connfd when the server wants to close the connection and then recall accept in order to make a new connfd ? I was planning on using the nonblock flag in order to allow accept to wait (in a thread).

Comment: @mont_ how should the client do to create a new connection to the same port? should they restart everything from the beginning?

Comment: @a_confused_student yes, the client would need to close its existing socket, create a new socket, and `connect()` it to the server again

Comment: @a_confused_student the main point of enabling the non-blocking flag is so you DON'T have to use threads. Multiple non-blocking sockets can be processed on a single thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I try to accept but after closing connfd socket, client manages to connect but server returns a negative socket number meaning that the connection was not possible how could this be?

Comment: @a_confused_student `errno` will tell you why `accept()` failed. The code you have shown is not closing the `connfd` that `accept()` returned, it is closing the listening `sockfd`. You should close only the connected `connfd` that `accept()` returned, leave the listening `sockfd` open so you can call `accept()` on it again. You need to call `accept()` in a loop for as long as the listening `sockfd` is active.